# Does anyone know of a pulldown menu plugin in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Does anyone know of a pulldown  menu plugin in javascript?**

- First, before you say: Just use the `select` tag, that is not what I am looking for. I am **looking for a plugin that forces the user to physically drag down a menu** (similarly to the top bar of an android/ios5 device). And should the user release the menu before it's half way down, the menu should return to normal state.
- Second, I am aware I could write one using jQuery drag, and that is what I will end up doing if I don't find a plugin... just thought I would ask before writing

Thanks,

Comment: If I understand correctly, OP is asking for something similar to Androids status bar on top of the screen, that can be slid down / opened by sliding with your finger on a touch screen (if the sliding has enough velocity, else it reverts to a status bar)

Comment: Exactly, I'll try to find a video

Comment: @Madmartigan, Found it: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=2kbSbkc_2Uo#t=340s

Comment: @Tomas: If a prebuilt plugin doesn't exist, how do we answer this question?

Comment: @Madmartigan, If one doesn't exist I will self answer none exists... I'll give it 6hrs

Comment: or even better, post your own solution once it's finished, you have 12 hours :)

Comment: [Challenge Accepted](http://fortnightlitpress.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/knapp01.png?w=480)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So... nothing...

**Good to know!** Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/JXeWA/46/