# Create a "pull down" div

Tags: javascript, css

I'm looking for a way to make a "pull down" div with Javascript/CSS.  Basically, I want my users to drag an HTML element and have another Div use something like jQuery's "slideDown" effect, but where it is directly linked with where they have pulled the other Div. 
Does that make any sense?

So if they pull the "Pull Me" Div only halfway down the screen the 2nd Div is only half visible.  Essentially, pulling down the shades on a window....I want that effect and I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: I think this post has what you are looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749921/does-anyone-know-of-a-pulldown-menu-plugin-in-javascript http://jsfiddle.net/JXeWA/46/